# Why does my assertion not raise an error?

Tags: c++, assert

My assert does not stop the program from continuing on. I do not have NDEBUG defined as I've seen from other questions on this matter. Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
   assert(0==1);
   std::cout << "Execution continues past the first assert" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Edit:
I am using VS2019

Edit2:
Thanks Arthur - as some have mentioned it looks like NDEBUG is defined somewhere. Is there a way to undefine this?

Comment: How are you compiling your program?

Comment: Run the preprocessor only and see what the assert expands to.

Comment: It sounds like the assert is optimized out by the compiler. Be sure you set the correct flags to avoid this.

Comment: You could try putting #ifdef NDEBUG #error 1 #else #error 2 #endif  to see if it's *really* defined.

Comment: " I do not have NDEBUG defined" where have you checked this? Have you looked in the preprocessor tab of project properties? This is the main place or would be defined in Visual Studio

Comment: "Is there a way to undefine this?" As I said in my comment above, look in preprocessor options of project properties.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I am using VS2019

Change the build type to Debug.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2019